# error IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF but actually it is ON

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I try to insert data to MSSQL DB through Entity Framework to table. It throws error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Product' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." but my ID have identity set to on. Anyone run into this trouble before? Of course i do not inserting value into Identity column
[image]

Answer (score 1):

funny thing happened , i changed identity on database table but forgot to update ADO.NET model...